# Referral traffic from main website to separately tracked subdomain showing as direct in Google Analytics

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics

We manage the subdomain website `subdomain.example.com` A completely separate company manage `www.example.com` which has a separate analytics account that we do not have access to.

We've noticed that traffic from the main website seems to be showing up in Analytics as direct traffic (destination URLs match up and it is WAY higher than direct should be for this site), and isn't showing as a referral.

I can't work out why this would be the case.

**Speculation:** I've noticed that the main website has three analytics codes on it, all for the same account. I've advised this is changed urgently to keep only the universal analytics code. Could this be something to do with the issue?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Google Analytics excludes referrals that come from the same hostname, so `www.example.com` would also apply to `subdomain.example.com`. That's why they're showing up as *direct*, not *referral*. You could remove the hostname from the Referral Exclusion List for your Google Analytics property, but bear in mind that this triggers a new session for the user. If you want to keep sessions consistent across domains/subdomains, you'll need to establish [cross-domain tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain).

Comment: works great. new sessions would be created on jumping across the domains.